Has anyone had experience in running Craft on DigitalOcean's App Platform?
I would like to look at deploying Craftcms to DigitalOcean's App Platform so that I can incorporate auto-scaling based on cpu load.  I would also use Redis for shared caching and continue to use DO's managed databases.
I would develop locally and deploy to DO's Container Registry which would auto-deploy to App Platform.
Any thoughts on this?
Thanks! =D
